# vertex u and v connected via an edge implies $C(u)=C(v)$

Tags: graph-theory

> Recall that a graph G is called connected if any two of its vertices are connected, otherwise, it is disconnected.
>
> Definition: $C(u)$ denotes the set of all vertices v in a graph G that are connected to u (via edges).

Claim:

Suppose that there is a path from u to v; or u-v exists.
Then, $C(u)=C(v)$

Suppose for simplicity that the edge $e_{uv}$ connects the vertex u and v.
$C(u)=v$ and $C(v)=u$

But this implies $C(u) \neq C(v)$

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write $C(u)=v$ since LHS is a set and RHS is a vertex. Ditto $C(v)=u$.

What you mean to say is that $v \in C(u)$ and $u \in C(v)$. From here you can conclude (after some argument) that indeed $C(v) = C(u)$. Can you prove it?

Comment: A hint would be helpful

Comment: Here goes: clearly, $v \in C\left ( u \right )$ and $u \in C\left ( v \right )$
Indeed, the subgraph induced by $C\left ( u \right )$ contains u and the subgraph induced by $C\left ( v \right )$ contains v. 
Then, $C\left ( u \right )=C\left ( v \right )$ as is required.

Comment: @Mathematicing ok. More precisely, I would prove a lemma that if $v \in C(u)$ then $C(v) \subseteq C(u)$. The proof is to let $x \in C(v)$ then there is a $x \to v$ path $P_x$ in $G$. Since $v \in C(u)$ there is a $v \to u$ path $p$ in $G$, so $P_x \to p$ forms a $x \to u$ walk in $G$, and this $x \in C(u)$...